# Why isn't this IF statement working?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an `IF` formula I am working on, that will not work. The formula I have is `=IF(D2=Emergency Services, U2-L2, IF D2=General Construction, U2-AA2)`.

In column D I have a formula built to return general construction or emergency services. Based on the type of service I need excel to subtract the date from the time the home was inspected to the time it took to start work.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to something more suitable, perhaps "IF formula not working".

Comment: You need to follow the formula syntax. IF(..., ..., ...) the 2nd if does not have the ('s and )'s nor a false parameter . Additionally, a text comparison needs its text to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things causing this not to work.

1. The
   [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
   syntax of your formula is wrong.
2. You nested an additional `IF` statement incorrectly. It needs to be treated just like it is on its own within the formula.
3. Performing logical checks on text requires the use of quotes,
   `"text"`.

Your formula should look like this;

`=IF(D2="Emergency Services", SUM(U2-L2), IF(D2="General Construction", SUM(U2-AA2), ))`

*Note: Make sure each `(` has a closing `)` to match.*

Answer (score 0):

Set up a static cell with "Emergency Services" and another with "General Construction". They can be hidden cells or on a different sheet, but you will reference these in the formula and make the formula dynamic if these terms change. For this example `Cell F1 = "Emergency Services"` and `Cell F2 = "General Construction"`

`IF(D2=F1,U2-L2,IF(D2=F2,U2-AA2,"<Text here for when neither criteria is met>")`

As LPChip mentioned, the IF() syntax is:

IF( `Formula which will evaluate to true or false` , `Outcome when true` , `Outcome when false` )

The formula I provided will check the initial statement, D2=F2. If it is true, it returns your value. If it is false, it performs the next `IF()` calculation.